# Issue defining code as XSL 2.0 but it still functions as XSL 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I hope this is a dumb user error - but - I have an XSLT file that should be using XSL 2.0 - however, whenever I try to use XSL 2.0 functions, like replace() for example, I get an error saying the function is not recognized

> System.Xml.Xsl.XsltException: 'replace()' is an unknown XSLT function.

I interpret this error to mean that the file is not getting properly defined or processed as XSL 2.0 but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is how I construct the version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Well you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor to use XSLT 2.0, like the .NET version of Saxon 9 or like XmlPrime. Microsoft does not support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Sheesh - thanks Microsoft

Comment: Are you trying to use XSLT 2.0 for replace() or for other enhancements? Some can be implemented in XSLT 1.0 directly or through embedded script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to ensure there is an answer: you are using an XSLT processor (System.Xml.Xsl) that lacks support for XSLT 2.0.